# Common bottom layout in all the tabs of TabHost in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost with 4-5 tabs. I want to have a similar bottom for all the tabs. Is there any way we can add a bottom to all the tabs? Or do I need to place the xml code in every layout file.

Please let me know if any one has the solution.

Regards

Sunil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the `<include>` option in your layout files.

Define the common footer in a layout file all by itself - `e.g tab_footer.xml` - and then include it into the the other layouts as follows:

```
<include layout="@layout/tab_footer">
```

You can find out more about `<include>` in [this post on the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html).

One thing that isn't mentioned in that post: if you want to override any `layout` parameters when you use `<include>` make sure you override `layout_width` and `layout_height` (even if they're not changing) otherwise your values for other parameters will be silently ignored.