# how to apply master page concept in android application?

Tags: android

I want common logout action to all pages in android application.i have common template that contain logout option. but i repeat the logout function to all activity. how to resolve this problem.

Comment: [I need sample example with common template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to extend a common Activity, as someone else suggested. You are able to extends only from one class, that's why you would do something like this:

```
public class CommonActivity extends Activity {
     // Here you implement log out methods
}

public class ParticularActivity extends CommonActivity {
    // Here you put your particular class variables and methods
}
```

This way, you have the logout functionality in every activity, all you have to do is extends the common one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base activity which extends Activity. Write the logic for logout in it. Then extend this class in all activities of the app.

Comment: [but i can't extend more than one activity]

Comment: Give some example for Base activity

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- extend Activity class and implement the functionality there, your activities would extend this class to provide same functionality
- use [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) - create some helper class which contains needed functionality

With first approach you will run into problems when you'll need to extend existing Activities in Android (e.g. ListActivity, TabActivity, etc.)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054903/android-bottom-bar-menu-onclick-actions/6055252#6055252).

Comment: Give some example for BaseActivity

Comment: i edited the answer, i have added link to another question's answer (also by me)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using XML file.

I am just creating runtime view from XML file , and add it to the Activity layout.

I have created method for that

```
public static void setLoginview(Context ctx, RelativeLayout layout) {
    LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.loginheader, null);    
    layout.addView(myView);
    try {
        layout.getChildAt(0).setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

ctx is the application contetx and layout is the layout in which i want to add that view.